# How to make notification work with sound this not working with sound or even default notification sound in android

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, push-notification, push

How to make notification work in this Php laravel project with sound this not working with sound or even default notification sound in android

```
public function toFcm($notifiable)
{
    $message = new FcmMessage();
    $notification = [
        'title'        => "New Order #".$this->order->id." to ".$this->order->foodOrders[0]->food->restaurant->name,
        'body'         => $this->order->user->name,
        'icon'         => $this->order->foodOrders[0]->food->restaurant->getFirstMediaUrl('image', 'thumb'),
        'click_action' => "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
        'id' => '1',
        'status' => 'done',
    ];
    $message->content($notification)->data($notification)->priority(FcmMessage::PRIORITY_HIGH);

    return $message;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using setAndroid method:

```
 $message->content($notification)->data($notification)->priority(FcmMessage::PRIORITY_HIGH) ->setAndroid(
            AndroidConfig::create()
                ->setNotification(AndroidNotification::create()
                    ->setNotificationPriority(NotificationPriority::PRIORITY_DEFAULT())
                    ->setDefaultSound(true)
                ));
```

the method `setDefaultSound(true)` tells android to run the default sound.